# IllegalStateException occurs in mediaPlayer when start online streaming second time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a simple online audio streaming app.It has 4 buttons Play,Stop,Resume,Pause.When i press stop button,it works fine after that when i start again,application crashes.It gives the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setAudioStreamType(Native Method)
     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(MediaPlayer.java:1723)
     at com.onlinestreaming.MediaPlayerActivity.onClick(MediaPlayerActivity.java:48)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

this is what i have done

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.play:

                    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    pd.setMessage("Buffering");
                    pd.show();
                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                    mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
                    try {
                        // mp.setDataSource("http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3");
                        //mp.setDataSource("http://picosong.com/zkWc");
                        mp.setDataSource("http://songs1.djmazadownload.com/music/indian_movies/Banjo%20%282016%29/01%20-%20Bappa%20-%20Banjo%20%5BDJMaza.Cool%5D.mp3");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    mp.prepareAsync();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                break;

            case R.id.Stop:
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();

                break;

            case R.id.Resume:
                mp.start();
                break;

            case R.id.Pause:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                } else {
                    mp.start();
                }
                // mp.pause();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        pd.dismiss();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Prepared Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pd.setMessage("Playing.......");

        mp.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On stop button press, you are releasing the resource of the MediaPlayer object.

`release():`

> Releases resources associated with this MediaPlayer object. It is
>   considered good practice to call this method when you're done using
>   the MediaPlayer. In particular, whenever an Activity of an application
>   is paused (its onPause() method is called), or stopped (its onStop()
>   method is called), this method should be invoked to release the
>   MediaPlayer object, unless the application has a special need to keep
>   the object around. In addition to unnecessary resources (such as
>   memory and instances of codecs) being held, failure to call this
>   method immediately if a MediaPlayer object is no longer needed may
>   also lead to continuous battery consumption for mobile devices, and
>   playback failure for other applications if no multiple instances of
>   the same codec are supported on a device. Even if multiple instances
>   of the same codec are supported, some performance degradation may be
>   expected when unnecessary multiple instances are used at the same
>   time.

So remove mp.release() from stop button clicklistener.

```
 case R.id.Stop:
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
      break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `mp.release()` if the user clicks STOP. This will put the `MediaPlayer` in the 'End' state (see this [state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram)).

So if the user clicks START the next time, you have to use a new `MediaPlayer` instance because `setAudioStreamType()` may only be used in the following states (see the [MediaPlayer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States)):

> Idle, Initialized, Stopped, Prepared, Started, Paused, PlaybackCompleted